# Can I run build job only on the master branch using the BUILD_DISABLED environment variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running ci using gitlab's autodevops, and I would like to disable build job on working branches other than master because I don't need to run build jobs on other branches.

It looks like I can do this by specifying the branch in rules:if in gitlab-ci.yaml, but can I do that using only the ci/cd environment variable BUILD_DISABLED?

Comment: If you have `.gitlab-ci.yml` you can add `only: [master]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed impossible to run the job on only the master branch using the environment variable BUILD_DISABLED.

Use only statement or rules statement and It can realize.